# Line 1034: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x6020000000d0 overflowed to 0x6020000000cf (stl_vector.h)

Tags: c++, graph, c++17, runtime-error, breadth-first-search

I am trying to solve leetcode problem 200. Number of Islands and I am getting this error Line 1034: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x6020000000d0 overflowed to 0x6020000000cf (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:34

```
class Solution {
public:
    int numIslands(vector<vector<char>>& grid) {
        if(grid.size() == 0) return 0;
        
        int r = grid.size();
        int c = grid[0].size();
        
        vector<vector<int>>vis(r,vector<int>(c,0));
        
        int islands = 0;
        
        for(int i =0 ;i<r;i++){
            for(int j =0  ;j<c;j++){
                if(grid[i][j]=='1' && vis[i][j]==0){
                    bfs(i,j,grid,vis);
                    islands++;
                }
            }
        }
        return islands;
    }
    void bfs(int i ,int j,vector<vector<char>>& grid,vector<vector<int>>&vis){
        deque<pair<int,int>>q;
        q.push_back({i,j});
        vis[i][j]=1;
        while(!q.empty()){
            int row = q.front().first;
            int col = q.front().second;
            q.pop_front();
            vector<pair<int,int>> directions = {{1,0},{-1,0},{0,1},{0,-1}};
            for( auto dir: directions){
                int r = row+dir.first;
                int c = col+dir.second;
                if((r>=0 && r<grid.size()) && (col>=0 && col<grid[0].size()))
                {
                    if(grid[r][c] == '1' && vis[r][c] == 0){
                    q.push_back({r,c});
                    vis[r][c]=1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
};
```

But this code is working fine in my local compiler. Can anyone please guide me about what have I done wrong here?

Comment: Simple typo `if((r>=0 && r<grid.size()) && (col>=0 && col<grid[0].size()))` should be `if((r>=0 && r<grid.size()) && (c>=0 && c<grid[0].size()))`

Comment: Remember *working fine in my local compiler* is one possible outcome of [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

Comment: @john thanks a lot it solved my problem, I was so frustrated that I overlooked it.